# Virtual Desktop Customization in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

Are there any tools or settings for Customization of Virtual Desktops in Windows 10 Home?
I tried searching many pre existing articles on Stack, but all of these seem not to work on current Windows 10 versions. Tools like [Dexpot](https://dexpot.de/) and [Virtual Desktop Enhancer](https://github.com/sdias/win-10-virtual-desktop-enhancer) all seem not working within the current Windows Editions.

Would like to know if there are any tools or just any settings files to modify. All I want to do is change the desktop names, add wallpapers and create hotkeys for transitions

My Device Specifications:
HP 15 series laptop
Windows 10 Home Version 19093 -- updated to 20H2 now
OS Build: 18363.1139

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tool which performs the tool exactly like what I want it to do.

It's a Microsoft Store app: [SylphyHorn](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/sylphyhorn/9nblggh58t01)

This application is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Grabacr07/SylphyHorn)

However, these do not provide options to change wallpapers. And have a slight delay in animations. Also no notifications and hotkeys have issues.

A forked version [SylphyHornEx](https://github.com/ViRb3/SylphyHornEx) which is a much better replacement to SylphyHorn; it consumes comparable memory and processing power(about 50 MB of memory and under a 10th of a percent processing power on modern machines). Also, this tool does provide all means to work over the desktops. Also it has been updated for the 20H2 version.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 Version 2004 enables you to edit a virtual desktop's name by clicking on it in the desktop selector.  Version 2004 became available on my PCs in late October 2020.

Microsoft Store is not a place I normally check, but it shows a couple of inexpensive utilities for customizing wallpapers, hotkeys, and (the first one) desktop names.  Their release dates look current.  I have not tried either.

- [Virtual Desktop Enhancer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/virtual-desktop-enhancer/9npq3fkglngq?activetab=pivot:overviewtab#): "Enhance your experience with Windows Virtual Desktops.  Keep control of your Virtual Desktops." (*This looks different from [Virtual Desktop Enhancer on GitHub](https://github.com/sdias/win-10-virtual-desktop-enhancer/)*).
- [WS Virtual Desktop Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ws-virtual-desktop-tool/9n5wrj22t733?activetab=pivot:overviewtab): "WS Virtual Desktop Tool is our utility that improves upon the Windows 10 Virtual Desktop feature."

In addition, many people find [VDesk](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk) useful for starting a Windows application on a specified desktop number.  I use it on Windows 10 Home 1903 and 2004.

Comment: I tried those, however, these didn't work on edition 1903; which I was using. I found this comment from some other people as well. However, WS Virtual Tool does work on my 20H2 machine.